# Xamarin class XAM110 projects MyTunes.Droid and MyTunes.iOS won't load

Tags: xamarin

I am in the trial of Xamarin University trying to decide if it is worth joining.  But I keep running into roadblocks with the self-guided classes.  Right now my issue is that in the XAM110 class (Intro to Cross-Platform Development), Visual Studio cannot load the MyTunes.Droid or MyTunes.iOS projects for the MyTunes solution I downloaded from the class materials.  The projects indicate "needs migration" in Solution Explorer, but when I try to reload the project, the error says "the project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them".  I am using VS Enterprise 2017 Version 15.5.5, Xamarin 4.8.760, Xamarin.Android SDK 8.1.5.0, Xamarin.iOS 11.6.1.4.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you should contact XU support

Comment: I fixed this problem finally by uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio 2017.